# Force required on a projectile to maintain its initial velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile

As per the Newton's Second Law;
$$\mathbf F = ma$$
and,

$$ \mathbf a = \frac{v-u}{t}$$

and, the initial velocity of a projectile propelled with an angle $\theta$ should be,

$$\mathbf v_i = \sqrt\frac{dg}{2sin\theta}$$

Now, the thing that's confusing is the force required on a projectile to maintain its initial velocity when the final velocity of the projectile is unknown.

Is it possible to explain the physics behind all this to someone with a background in nothing more than high school physics so that the force required to propel a projectile can be determined theoretically?

Comment: If you're in a situation where the range of the projectile is well-approximated by your first equation, then you're in a situation where drag forces are negligible and you don't need to worry about them in the launch phase either.

Comment: Concerning the new question:  I'm not sure what you mean by it.  The amount of force required on a particle to "maintain its initial velocity" is zero;  that's what Newtons' First Law says.  Can you try rephrasing your question?

Comment: What I'm trying to do actually is propel a projectile using a pneumatic cylinder and this projectile is at rest initially. By projectile equations, I find the initial velocity required to propel the projectile up to a known range. The thing that's confusing is the force required to propel this projectile using a pneumatic cylinder. If I find out the force required I could size the cylinder as per the force required to propel the projectile.